# Exception handling issue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am currently trying to add an exception handler on some code. That code simply creates an instance.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
```

I have tried:

```
try 
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline); 
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    // code here
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

> Error  1 The name 'request' does not exist in the current context.

By adding the try on to the statement. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hint: I suspect OP was trying to access `request` in the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

The chances are that the exception is happening not when you try to create the request, but when you try to get the response:

```
HttpWebResponse response;
try 
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception here
}
```

When using try-catch blocks you need to surround the line of code that fails.  (You probably need to read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) some more).

Bear in mind when using try-catch blocks that anything that you intend to use outside of the `try` block needs to be scoped accordingly (delcare it outside of the try block, as I have done above).

Comment: Actually, it is, since the maximum available requests might already be consumed

Comment: @Johnathan According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx) the only exceptions thrown by create would be due to an invalid uri or a local permissions problem.  No request is sent until the `GetResponse` method is called and so any connection related exception certainly can't be thrown by `Create` as it wouldn't have happened yet!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to use your "request" variable outside of the try block.
You need to declare it outside of the block if you want to use it after the try/catch block.

```
HttpWebRequest request;
try 
{
    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
// Your request variable won't be destroyed now, you can use it here
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what your looking for is;

```
    try 
    {
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(firstline);
     HttpWebResponse HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse
     if(HttpWResp.StatusCode ==200)
    {
    //Sucessfull code
    }
    else
    {
        //fail   code

     }

}

catch(Exception ex)
{
// Exception codee here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that that the exception is not thown in the line that you think. Try to add an [Application level](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/08/top-level-exception-handling-in-windows-forms-applications-part-1/) exception handler. And then, use `Environment.StackTrace` to track the line the application failed on.

If you're using Visual Studio, use Debug exceptions and check Thrown for Common Language Runtime exceptions.

Hope it helps.